# intellij Import eclipse

Tags: import, intellij-idea

I just recently start to try to move to intellij. After trying it several time i have decided to make the big move. I have downloaded an evaluation of ultimate.

hence i have decided to import my project from eclipse. However i am having some difficulties.

1- When I import a project as a module (inside a a project in Intellij) for which i clearly specify where i would like the project to be imported (i.e. "Keep project and module files in") (i.e. in a folder of the original name inside the current intellij encompassing project folder)

```
 >>>Intellij do not import the files but references the eclipse project from whithin a new folder that it create. I do not want to mix my source. I want to duplicate the source and have it in intellij. But intellij, is actually pointing to my eclipse project.
       This is an issue for me. Is there a way to avoid that ?
```

The question how does the import actualy behave. Does it duplicate the all files and create a new dir with all the duplicate files and the conig, or does it simply create a new dir, with conf files that point to the old dir.

What should i do, if i want to go from a project A in clipse to a project A' in Intellij with A' as a clone of A where both are fully independent project ?

Can any one help or assist on this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import will not duplicate any files, it will create IntelliJ metadata (`.idea, *.iml, *.ipr`) files inside your project, so you can work on the same codebase with both IDE simultaneously. Also, you can establish a two-way sync, with Eclipse project configuration changes synced to IntelliJ module and vice versa.

Unless you want to create an independent copy of your original project(as you mentioned in the question), then just copy the contents into a new directory and import the cloned code into IntelliJ. The changes you make in one project will not be reflected in another project.

If you are using git, then you can simply clone the existing git repository.

```
$ git clone my-eclipse-project my-idea-project
```